# Compare the entered value with a row in csv file

Tags: python

Basically, I need to check if the entered value is the same as the fourth value in each line of csv file.

E.g. :

csv file looks like that:

**Name, email, phone number, Superior, some data, some data, some data**

**Name, email, phone number, Premier, some data, some data, some data**

**Name, email, phone number, Suite, some data, some data, some data**

**Name, email, phone number, Superior, some data, some data, some data**

Entered value = **Superior**

for loop checks every line in the csv file and does actions if values are the same.

My code at the moment looks like that :

```
def readFile(aFile):
#read a file and return a list
        with open(aFile, 'r') as inFile: 
            reader = csv.reader(inFile)
            aList = [row for row in reader]
        return aList


    @app.route('/addBooking', methods = ['POST'])
    def addBooking():
        #read the booking list from file
        fileName = 'static\\bookings.csv'
        bookList = readFile(fileName)
        fileName1 = 'static\\errors.csv'
        errorList = readFile(fileName1)
        # add an entry to the bookings list
        name = (request.form[('name')])
        email = (request.form[('email')])
        phone = (request.form[('number')])
        room = (request.form[('room')])
        quantity = (request.form[('quantity')])
        inDate = (request.form[('date1')])
        outDate = (request.form[('date2')])
        #we have only 15 rooms of each type
        #so the website will show an error if an user tries to book more than 15 rooms
        if int(quantity)>15: 
            return render_template('booking.html', errorList = errorList)
        else:
            for line in bookList:
                if room == line[4]:
                    if (int(quantity)+int(line[5]))>15:
                        return render_template('booking.html', errorList = errorList)
                        break
                    else:
                        newBook=[name,email,phone,room,quantity,inDate,outDate]
                        bookList.append(newBook)
                        #save the bookings list to the file
                        writeFile(bookList, fileName)
                        return redirect('booking')
                        break
                else:
                    newBook=[name,email,phone,room,quantity,inDate,outDate]
                    bookList.append(newBook)
                    #save the bookings list to the file
                    writeFile(bookList, fileName)
                    return redirect('booking')
                    break
```

Does someone have any ideas how to make this for loop working ? Thank you !

Comment: You can remove every `break`.

Comment: but it won't solve the problem, right ?

Comment: Any feedback on why it is not working currently? What is going wrong from what you expect.